# Finding records in Oracle DB with non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to find all the records in an Oracle DB which have non-alphanumeric characters. I am trying to use the following, but it does not return anything. And I know there are records with non-alphanumeric characters:

select * from users where first_name  LIKE '%[^a-z0-9A-Z]%'

Comment: You need to use REGEXP_LIKE

Comment: please tell more exactly, do you need records with **only** non-alphanumeric characters, or records, which contains non-alphanumeric characters **also**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from users where  REGEXP_LIKE (first_name, '^[^0-9a-z]+$', 'i');
```

Comment: This would show only records with exclusively non-alphanumeric characters. It would work if you dropped the anchors `^$`.

Answer (score 6):

without the not you just get those with alpha numeric characters.

```
SELECT * FROM users where not REGEXP_LIKE (first_Name, '^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$')
```